# How to convert a string into a list as a single element?

Tags: python

I am having string as below:

> a ='sruthi'

I want to convert this string into list like below:

> ['sruthi']

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try `a = [a]`

Comment: `list(a) == ['s', 'r', 'u', 't', 'h', 'i']`. If you really had to you could do `list([a])
 == ['sruthi']` but why do that when you could just do as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ said.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Loving the username...

Comment: i want like ['sruthi'] this . the entire string has to come as a single word,

Comment: @Aditi That is not a valid duplicate... you may need to look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a ='sruthi'
>>>
>>> list([a])
['sruthi']
>>>
```

or like in the comments above...

```
>>> a ='sruthi'
>>> a = [a]
>>> a
['sruthi']
```

pick your flavor...

Answer (score 0):

```
a ='sruthi'
result = a.split()
print result
```

o/p : `['sruthi']`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ As per the question. Where is the space in the mentioned question ?

Comment: If you are going to answer a question like this, you may want the answer to work for more than just a handful of inputs... just saying :)

Comment: Ahh .,. Okay :D

Comment: Also it is best to add some explenation to your answer as to why this piece of code provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

The list function breaks the string into list & consider the each character as separate as list element .
While the split function convert the whole string into the single element of list .

I am also attach the screenshot of the output .

---

```
a ='sruthi'
print("String a : " , a)

#Now convert into list by calling list function
print("List a : " , list(a))

print("List a : " , a.split())
```

---

[image]